# How to get data back from ICMP Time Exceeded packet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, network-programming

All I want to do is try to make my own little `traceroute` in python...
Actually, I have that much working already. What I'm trying to do is asynchronously accumulate traceroutes to multiple hosts. In order to do this, I'm sending packets that include a single byte which servers as a unique id for every tracer. The problem is, I don't see this id anywhere in the response.

Here's a simple test MCVE I wrote to demonstrate using one packet sent to one host with a TTL of 1:

```
import socket

# I need two sockets, because I'm sending datagrams
# (to avoid manual packet construction)
# but I'm receiving raw icmp packets
sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
receiver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, proto=1) # 1 is icmp

sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 1)
sender.sendto(bytes([42]), ("8.8.8.8", 1)) #using google public dns for testing

pkt, addr = receiver.recvfrom(65536)

# The following line raises ValueError
print( pkt.index(42) )

# ... and so would this one
print( pkt.index(bytes([42])) )
```

So you see, I'm just trying to send one packet to one host with a TTL of 1. I get a response, and I've parsed through it by hand enough to know that the 21st byte is `11`, and the 22nd byte is `0` - which indicates a proper ttl exceeded ICMP packet. The address that it returns from is also the first address I see in a normal `traceroute` to 8.8.8.8

However, the byte with value `42` cannot be found anywhere in the response. What happened to my data? According to [multiple](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg11.htm) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded), the first 8 bytes of my original datagram's data section should be included in the response, and yet I can't seem to find a single one of them.

If it matters, I'm running Python 3.6.3 on MacOSX High Sierra, and I gave the script the root privileges it needs to open sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused by what is returned. The first eight octets of the *IP payload* (the datagram contained in the IP packet) are returned. That is large enough to include a UDP header (eight octets), but none of the UDP payload. The goal in including eight octets is that you will have the TCP or UDP port numbers in order to identify the process that sent the original packet for which the TTL was exceeded. That allows IP to send the message to the correct process. This is detailed in [*RFC 792, Internet Control Message Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792):

> Time Exceeded Message
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |     Type      |     Code      |          Checksum             |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             unused                            |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |      Internet Header + 64 bits of Original Data Datagram      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> IP Fields:
>
> Destination Address
>
> The source network and address from the original datagram's data.
>
> ICMP Fields:
>
> Type
>
> 11
>
> Code
>
> 0 = time to live exceeded in transit;
>
> 1 = fragment reassembly time exceeded.
>
> Checksum
>
> The checksum is the 16-bit ones's complement of the one's complement
> sum of the ICMP message starting with the ICMP Type. For computing the
> checksum , the checksum field should be zero. This checksum may be
> replaced in the future.
>
> Internet Header + 64 bits of Data Datagram
>
> The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's
> data.  This data is used by the host to match the message to the
> appropriate process.  If a higher level protocol uses port numbers,
> they are assumed to be in the first 64 data bits of the original
> datagram's data.
>
> Description
>
> If the gateway processing a datagram finds the time to live field is
> zero it must discard the datagram.  The gateway may also notify the
> source host via the time exceeded message.
>
> If a host reassembling a fragmented datagram cannot complete the
> reassembly due to missing fragments within its time limit it discards
> the datagram, and it may send a time exceeded message.
>
> If fragment zero is not available then no time exceeded need be sent
> at all.
>
> Code 0 may be received from a gateway.  Code 1 may be received from a
> host.

Comment: This is why the standard `traceroute` sends each probe to a different UDP port. The port number can be extracted from the response, and that can be used to relate it to the probe packet.

Comment: See, that description is confusing. I assumed that the "Internet Header" was all of the header information from the whole internet suite stack - meaning both the IP header *and* the UDP header. Then it says that the it also contains "the first 64 bits of the original datagram's data", which I took to mean that this was the first 64 bits starting from the data section of the datagram, otherwise it should say "the first 64 bits of the datagram". IMO this could be a lot clearer.

Comment: When referring to the RFCs, remember that IP stands for Internet Protocol, so the Internet Header is the IP header. The datagram in this context is the IP payload, as IP (ICMP is an integral part of IP) knows nothing about the payload of the IP packet. IP knows what is in the protocol field (for IPv4, or Next Header field for IPv6), but it knows nothing about the actual protocol; the protocol field simply tells it to which process to send the payload of the received packet.